# Running/Debugging ASP.Net core applications without access to command prompt

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, command-prompt, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to develop an ASP.Net core app on a system using visual studio 2017 and .Net core 2.1. My organization has suddenly restricted us from Command prompt (not even by right-click -> run as admin). Subsequently, I amm getting an error sayin "HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure". Is there any work around for this or is command prompt access absolutely needed?

Comment: It is hard to know your problem since it is a general error you get.What is the log in [Windows Event Log](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/) (Application)?

Have you tried to delete the applicationhost.config (in {APPLICATION ROOT}\.vs\config\applicationHost.config) and rebuild app?

Do you have problem when run application using ProjectName from the drop down options available near the green 'run' button instead of IIS Express?

Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8134

Comment: Why are you not running it from visual studio start button ?

Comment: I am running it from visual studio. Also, deleting applicationHost.config shows "Cannot connect to IIS". Also, tried running the application using ProjectName from the drop down options available near the green 'run' button instead of IIS Express. It doesn't start. Obviously not being able to run cmd is the cause here. What I am trying to find is if there is any work around for this.